# Issue with creating a custom view with where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a page using PHP as a front end for my database. It is working properly, I have created a query in MYSQL with the WHERE clause and it runs perfectly but on PHP, it did not allow me to save that query in Custom View.

I need that query because I want end users to enter the team name to get the list of their desire team. But on PHP, I am not able to do that.

I use PHP Maker to create front end.

Below is the SQL Code of my Query

```
SELECT
emp_details_ees.Employee_Code,
emp_details_ees.Employee_Name,
post.Emp_Post,
designation.Employee_Designation,
team.Emp_Team,
base_station.Base_Station,
region.Region,
zone.Zone,
emp_details_ees.Employee_Company_Number,
emp_details_ees.Employee_Comapny_Email,
`status`.Emp_Status,
emp_details_ees.Employee_Personal_Address
FROM
base_station
INNER JOIN emp_details_ees ON emp_details_ees.Employee_Base_Station = base_station.basestation_id
INNER JOIN post ON emp_details_ees.Employee_Post = post.emppost_id
INNER JOIN designation ON emp_details_ees.Employee_Designation = designation.empdesignation_id
INNER JOIN region ON emp_details_ees.Employee_Region = region.region_id
INNER JOIN `status` ON emp_details_ees.Employee_Status = `status`.empstatus_id
INNER JOIN team ON emp_details_ees.Employee_Team = team.empteam_id
INNER JOIN zone ON emp_details_ees.Employee_Zone = zone.zone_id
WHERE
`status`.Emp_Status = 'Active' AND team.Emp_Team = [$Emp_Team]
ORDER BY
base_station.station_sortid ASC,
designation.designation_sortdid ASC;
```

If you could help me to clear out the confusion.

Comment: What are you trying to to ? Please explain!

Comment: I want user to enter the team name to get the list in PHP front end

Comment: Did you check the output of your SELECT QUERY ?

Answer (score 0):

Change [$Emp_Team] to {$Emp_Team} in you WHERE clause

Comment: PHP did not accept { instead of [ when you are using command to get desire data

Comment: Below is the SQL Code of my Query, is it a .php file or something else?

Comment: I use SQL code to create a custom view in PHP to get data from different folders.